# Projecting one object above another

Tags: modeling, mesh, texturing, uv, texture-painting

I am new to blender.
I have two wavefront objects, one is the drawing and another one is its 3d model. I want to place that drawing over the 3d model. Is there a way to do it? And what direction should I follow to achieve it?
Thank you. I have attached the screenshot for the same
[image]

A way by which the drawing will not levitate in the air, and clip to the ground mesh
[image]

Comment: when you say that you want to place it over, do you mean that the 3D object is flat and you want to mix its texture with this drawing? or is this drawing supposed to be a new object that will be transparent?

Comment: @moonboots Thanks for the reply. The drawing is flat and the ground object in 3d. Want to place the drawing over the ground object.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it in the material of your object itself: Create a new UVMap that you'll use for your drawing, put the *(Input) UV Map* node before the *Image Texture* with your drawing, mix the drawing with the existing material with a *Mix Shader*, use the alpha of the drawing as factor:

[image]

Comment: yes, but....can i use beta, gamma, delta, epsilon also?

Comment: @Chris, come on Chris, you come from the future but here in 2022 we are only at Blender 3, not Blender 25

Comment: we don't have 2055!? Really!? that's why this site looks so old-fashioned... :D So this is NOT retro-design!?!??! :D :D

Comment: @Chris, no you're really lost in the past Chris, sorry to tell you, btw please tell us how all this sh*tty geopolitical situation will end up, I mean if it doesn't create any time paradoxes of course, I don't want to disrupt the future

Comment: You mean after Russia declared war to USA and the atomic bombs were falling? The aliens had no more fun with this milky way simulation and restarted it again. For the 235. time....looks like humans don't learn :(

Comment: oh ok so we are all part of a kind of alien video game or something like that? I knew it

Comment: Yes. Matrix revealed that. It’s a movie from the aliens. It’s a wake up call. ‍♂️

Comment: Yes, our matrix has released the movie Matrix to make us believe that reality is real, but I'm not a fool

Comment: Of course you aren’t ‼️‼️‼️

Comment: @chris guys, im now reading stackexchange only for your absurd comment banter :)) so good

Comment: @JachymMichal : one day, when you will recognize that I made no jokes, you will become a believer. 

Comment: I feel a bit offended by Jachym's comment, we're talking serious matter here, like who we are, where we are going and why does Suzanne looks so much like Brigitte Macron, all very disturbing facts

Comment: @moonboots: don't worry. Jachym will regret this. The simulation had a bad ending for him in all tries except number 137 and 96. And there he had just luck....because some aliens from DX9-&§$4 (that's what it would be in your simple language) influenced it to his flavor.

Comment: and by the way: in 7 of the 235 tries so far you got really famous.... :D

Comment: 7 on 235 is really low, by the way are you taliking about tries or tris, because the matrix told me that we were actually living in ngons, not tris or quads, which is completely unintuitive. When I recommend ngons no one want to listen to me, hard to be the new Einstein

Comment: Of course we are living in ngons. But in 2055 we we live in ogons and working in new technology to live in pgons in 2057 hopefully.

Comment: O-gons? is it not this moldavian band who sang Dragostea Din Tei in the beginning of the 2000s? I knew that we were living in a nightmare